# AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist in Properties folder in Xamarin Studio project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm using Xamarin Studio to create Android app and I've got a problem with AndroidManifest.xml file. It wasn't created in 'Properties' folder, but I've noticed that it was generated in obj\Debug\android after build. My question is how can I control content of this generated file. I prefer to add permission directly in AndroidManifest.xml, not by non-abstract classes that derive from Activity and have ActivityAttribute declared on them (I'm aware of this possibility). Any idea why is doesn't exist in 'Properties'?

Comment: I'd just like to note that I'm currently running the latest version of Xamarin Studio, and I had to delete the Maninfest file the other day due to some weird crap that the IDE was injecting into it. After deleting the Manifest file, I refreshed the Solution Explorer and it had created a whole new Manifest file. So unless there's something preventing it from doing so, it should create one automagically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why it wasn't created for a new project. However, you can double click on the Android project in your solution and then a "Project Options" dialog should pop up. Click on "Android Application". If you don't have a manifest a button should appear to add one (this should add one to the Properties folder). If you do have one you can add permissions from the dialog.

[image: An example of the dialog after you double click the project in the solution explorer]